# how to pass a shallow copy of an array into a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, p5.js, interactive

I want to get a different slice of the array in the console.log depending on what button I press, however no matter what button I end up pressing I always get the last 20 elements of the array.
How can I make it behave as expected?

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var b;
      var NewArr = [];
      if (i % 20 == 0) {
        NewArr = array.slice(i, i + 20);
        b = createButton(i + "-" + (i + 20), NewArr);
        b.position(x, y + i * 1.5);
        b.mousePressed(function () {
          console.log(NewArr);
        });
      }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you meant `NewArr = array.slice(i, i + 20);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `let` instead of `var`.

`var` declarations are hoisted (there are many other answers/wiki articles about JS hoisting already if you want to read more) to the top of the current function scope, even you declare it inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much ^_^, it was a too simple solution and yet it worked!

Comment: If it solved your question please consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: Sure!,  but how can I do that? sorry, I'm new to this...

Comment: No problem, there should be a checkmark below the vote buttons, refer to the image in the Meta article: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235